# I have created a form field label dynamically using php/mysql

Tags: php, arrays, associative

i want to change the key. this is the output once i submitted the form.

```
Array ( 
    [year] => 1 
    [event_name] => 2 
    [Sno] => 6 
    [First_name] => kodeesswaran 
    [Last_name] => thanagaraju 
    [Dept/Class] => cse 
    [topice] => test 
)
```

i want to `replace[Dept/class] to [Dept_class]`.

what array function i want to use  to replace that `forward(/)`

Comment: Please enter subject more related to your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the `name="Dept/class"` attribute on the form to `name="Dept_class"`

Comment: the Dept/Class is coming dynamically how to replace / to _

Comment: can I ask why you need to rename the key?

Comment: Because, i have created a database column Dept_class when admin create a form,for show purpose i show the form label Dept/class.that i have maintained in different table,in database  i have replaced the dept/class to dept_class,then only  i can insert data to particular field so that only i want to change to / to _. once i created the table dynamically from form i have replace dept/class to dept_class.now i want to insert.